# Get guild id on start event | Discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am working on my discord bot and wanted to set different ready messages on different servers. In order to do that I have compare different guild ids on ready. How would I be able to do that?

I know that taking guild id from a message is:

```
message.guild.id
```

I also know that taking all guild ids on ready would go something like this:

```
const guilds = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id);
```

But how would I be able to compare a certain id to execute specific code for that guild? I am so close to figuring it out yet I am clueless on how to do this.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using an object or a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store key-value pairs between the guild ID you want to send a ready message to, and the message to send. For example:

```js
const readyMessages = {
  '1901864734235': 'I am online',
  '6714589374095': 'Hello it is I, I am here, here I am'
  '3876429867467': 'What is up',
};
```

You can then iterate through these pairs using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (or `Map#forEach()` if using a map, which would be significantly easier, but for the sake of simplicity, I'll use an object). `Object.entries()` will return an array of arrays, each inner array containing two values. The key and the value. Example:

```js
// in this example, you're associating
// each name with an age
const ages = {
  john: 23,
  mary: 16,
  jack: 24,
};

// this logs an array of arrays, each array representing 
// a property of this object
// the structure is [key, value] (in this case: [name, age]);
// all together, it looks like:
// [[name, age], [name, age], [name, age], [name, age]]
console.log(Object.entries(ages));
```

Now that your object is an array, you can use the ever-so-handy [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through every element. I'll show you how this can work by continuing our previous example:

```js
// in this example, you're associating
// each name with an age
const ages = {
  john: 23,
  mary: 16,
  jack: 24,
};

const entries = Object.entries(ages);

// use array destructuring to get the
// name and age
entries.forEach(([name, age]) => {
  console.log(`${name} is ${age} years old`);
});

// alternatively, without using array destructuring,
// you could do this for the same result:
// entries.forEach((data) => {
//   console.log(`${data[0]} is ${data[1]} years old`);
// });
```

In your situation, the two parameters when destructuring will be `guildID` and `message`. If you have the guildID, you can simply fetch the guild using [`GuildManager#cache#get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=cache).

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID);
```

Then, you can get the channel to send it off of `guild`. And finally, using the `message` parameter:

```js
channel.send(message);
```

---

> Then, you can get the channel to send it off of `guild`

This is a bit vague. Getting the channel would be easy if they all shared the same name, such as `ready-messages`, so that you could use the same code for every guild. But what if each guild had a specific channelID you want to send to?

(I'd really recommend using a `Map` for everything below if you can, but I'll continue with an object just in case)

It just means you have to put more data in each property! Instead of using the format:

```js
{
  'guildID': 'message'
}
```

You can make the value *yet another* object. This way you can store any amount of data relating to the ready message per guild. the new structure will look like:

```js
{
  'guildID': {
    'channelID': '324728974398234',
    'message': 'I am alive',
  }
}
```

Now, instead of the two destructured parameters being `server` and `message`, it will be `server` and *`data`*. Then you can use `data.channelID` and `data.message` for their respective needs.

```js
const guild = /* ... */
const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(data.channelID);
channel.send(data.message);
```

Comment: I have read and tried what you've told and explained here (thanks for the detailed explanation too learned one or two things here) but I have a question because I can't get it to work and I think that's because I didn't understand the last part of your explanation. 
Here is the code 

readyMessagesArray.forEach(([server, message]) => {
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(server);
        var channel = guild.channels.cache.get('716688508038807591');
        channel.send(message);
});
@Lioness100

Comment: I would be able to get the channel id using the guild from the array only for one of the guilds no? Or am i mistaking here?

Comment: Glad I could help